# O que significa id="primary" class="content-area" se não existem no arquivo style.css?

Tags: html5, wordpress, css3, front-end

Estou começando agora a desenvolver temas para o WordPress e estou estudando o tema padrão do mesmo. Porém até agora não entendi qual o significado dessas ID's e classes que não existem configurações de suas propriedades em lugar nenhum. Procurei na internet e não encontrei nada relacionado.

Ex. na index.php: `id="primary" class="content-area"`

Ex. no header.php: `id="page" class="hfeed site"`

Essas ID's e classes não existem em lugar nenhum, seria só para "padronizar visualmente" o código pra ficar mais claro? Removendo elas não acontece nada no Tema, o estilo permanece do mesmo jeito em suas respectivas DIVs.

Comment: Creio que seja só para exemplificar como você mesmo disse, se você removeu e não houve alteração então não servem para nada.

Comment: Qual é sua pergunta @skidrow?

Answer (score 4):

Primeiramente, vale lembrar que a presença de classes ou IDs em tags `HTML` não tem como propósito exclusivo a estilização através de um arquivo `.css`. Veja [neste fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zk7h8er/1/) que `div#click` não tem nenhum tipo de estilização. Usei o ID apenas para atrelar uma função ao evento de click sobre ele.

Partindo deste ponto, fiz uma busca pela classe `.hfeed` em todos os arquivos do WP (não apenas os do tema), e no arquivo `\wp-admin\js\bookmarklet.js`, linha 115, encontrei o seguinte trecho de código:

```
if ( document.body.getElementsByClassName ) {
    content = document.body.getElementsByClassName( 'hfeed' )[0];
}
```

Ou seja, `.hfeed` vai ser usado pra alguma coisa. Se você retirar a classe, essa funcionalidade se perde. De acordo com o comentário do [renan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4808/renan), essa classe em especial é usada para coisas como feed de blog e etc.

Na sequência, procurei pela classe `.content-area`, e só encontrei ocorrências dentro das pastas de tema. E, dentro do *twentyfifteen*, eis que ela não tem referência em lugar nenhum. Nem no `JS`, no `css`, nada! No *twentyfourteen* ainda é possível encontrar trechos como:

```
.ie7 .content-area {
    padding-top: 48px;
 }
```

que ainda tratam um pouco da estilização do conteúdo, seja ela qual for. Mas no *twentyfifteen*, ela só aparece `PHP`, como markup puro, sem eventos ou estilos atrelados a ela. Isso, por fim, torna a classe inútil? Veja, concorda que ler

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        # ...
        # ...
    </main><!-- .site-main -->
</div><!-- .content-area -->
```

é muito mais fácil do que ler

```
<div>
    <main>
        # ...
        # ...
    </main>
</div>
```

?

Com as classes (e os comentários, veja) fica muito mais fácil entender qual é o papel de cada um dos elementos, e entender as suas responsabilidades dentro do funcionamento do template, ainda mais no WP, onde esses papéis são sempre bem definidos. Fora que, caso você precise estilizar alguma coisa (por exemplo, trocar o fundo de *todas* as áreas de conteúdo para azul), a classe já está lá para você. Torna o seu trabalho mais fácil, não?

Resumindo, as classes são inúteis? Não!